# Why doesn't npm modules' commands work in VSCode Terminal?

Tags: node.js, powershell, visual-studio-code, npm, terminal

If I type any Nodejs command in Vscode Terminal there comes the error

> The term "nodemon" was not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if the path is correct (if included),
> and repeat the process.

It also doesn't works in external Terminal but it works in Terminal which isn't opened by VSCode.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you install the module?

Comment: Have you restarted VSCode after installation, is nodemon in your PATH Environment variable?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski npm init didnt worked in vscode so i used powershell

Comment: `npm init` doesn't install anything by default

Comment: @Marc In Path there is C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i also used npm install in powershell

Comment: Did you install `nodemon` globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using windows, you should use the `npx` command to run modules.

It should come preinstalled alongside `npm`

```
npx nodemon
```

Comment: I had the same Error using this command

Comment: Does the npm command work? @JannikStach

Comment: no, not in vscode but changing the System enviroment Variables worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the variables:

- `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`
- `C:\Users\(your Username)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

are present in your system environment variables under the path tab.